# Raster PCA in R

Tags: r, raster, pca, summary

I have 19 raster files loaded into R as a raster stack. I performed a PCA of the rasters with the function rasterPCA() of the RStoolbox package. I need only the first 5 principal components, so I set nComp = 5.
If I call summary() on the output of the PCA I get the result on the top of the screenshot: the first PCs explain, as expected, most of the variance of the original rasters and proportion of variance decreases for each component. Instead, with the function loadings() it appears that each component explains an equal amount of variance (bottom of the screenshot, I cut part of the output).
Can someone help me?
Thank you all
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93Iv1.png)

Comment: I agree that the `nComp=` argument does not do what the manual page says it does. You should contact the package maintainer: `maintainer("RStoolbox")`.

Comment: @dcarlson actually I think `nComp=` argument could refer only to the number of raster layers stored on the output and not to the overall result of PCA.
Thank you for your answer.